# Tracking daily hard drive usage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, monitoring

Is there a way I can track all hard drive usage (applications, OS processes, page files, and indexes)? I would want the statistics broken down per drive and into read and writes. I am running Windows 7 64 bit and I have multiple drives.

Answer (score 0):

bit9 might be able to do this for you.  I know it calculates parity on all files that are accessed...

https://www.bit9.com

Depends on what you are actually trying to do...

Comment: Mainly statistics tracking. I'm going to get a SSD and I kind of want to know how much I write to my fast primary disk (but I am almost constantly downloading to my storage drives). I know I'm probably not going to hit any limits with my usual usage but I'm just kind of curious.

Comment: I wouldnt worry about it... just get a fast system disk, and put slow stuff on the big spin disks.  If you notice latency on an app or two, put them on the SSD

Comment: I'm not really worried, the question is mainly for curiosity's sake.